# Deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed

Tags: django, azure, deployment, web-applications, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy a django project in azure from GitHub repository but I am getting error during the deployment. I am getting this error:

Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2053869Z ##[error]Deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.

How can I resolve it?

````
2022-01-02T15:07:42.4101966Z with:
2022-01-02T15:07:42.4102399Z   app-name: stockprojection
2022-01-02T15:07:42.4102889Z   slot-name: Production
2022-01-02T15:07:42.4115035Z   publish-profile: ***
2022-01-02T15:07:42.4115476Z   package: .
2022-01-02T15:07:42.4116058Z ##[endgroup]
2022-01-02T15:07:43.9633760Z Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
2022-01-02T15:32:51.1581899Z Updating submodules.
2022-01-02T15:32:51.1583435Z Preparing deployment for commit id 'f47d703f2a'.
2022-01-02T15:32:51.1584587Z Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2022-01-02T15:32:51.1585520Z Running oryx build...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1954843Z Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9 -i /tmp/8d9ce01a48e2911 --compress-destination-dir -p virtualenv_name=antenv --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1957351Z Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1958337Z You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1992563Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1993572Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20210826.1, Commit: f8651349d0c78259bb199593b526450568c2f94a, ReleaseTagName: 20210826.1
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1994721Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1995241Z Build Operation ID: |da22zDrMO/Q=.cac2beba_
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1996043Z Repository Commit : f47d703f2a594452a83ae4301b5d6ce8
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1996497Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1997051Z Detecting platforms...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1997609Z Detected following platforms:
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1998100Z   python: 3.9.7
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1999279Z Version '3.9.7' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.1999807Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2000549Z Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8d9ce01a48e2911'.
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2001012Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2001533Z Copying files to the intermediate directory...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2002087Z Done in 0 sec(s).
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2002345Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2002782Z Source directory     : /tmp/8d9ce01a48e2911
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2003367Z Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2003726Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2003938Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2004699Z Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.9.7' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7'...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2005361Z Downloaded in 1 sec(s).
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2005817Z Verifying checksum...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2006290Z Extracting contents...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2006715Z Done in 24 sec(s).
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2006959Z 
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2007462Z Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2008171Z Creating directory for command manifest file if it doesnot exist
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2008806Z Removing existing manifest file
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2009356Z Python Virtual Environment: antenv
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2009917Z Creating virtual environment...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2010491Z Activating virtual environment...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2011006Z Running pip install...
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2011541Z [15:08:42+0000] Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2012658Z [15:08:42+0000]   Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2013461Z [15:08:43+0000] Collecting Django==3.2.7
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2014278Z [15:08:43+0000]   Downloading Django-3.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2015027Z [15:08:45+0000] Collecting djangorestframework==3.13.0
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2016199Z [15:08:45+0000]   Downloading djangorestframework-3.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (958 kB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2018261Z [15:08:46+0000] Collecting matplotlib==3.4.2
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2019288Z [15:08:48+0000]   Downloading matplotlib-3.4.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.3 MB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2020051Z [15:08:49+0000] Collecting nltk==3.6.2
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2020817Z [15:08:49+0000]   Downloading nltk-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2021432Z [15:08:50+0000] Collecting nsepy==0.8
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2022116Z [15:08:50+0000]   Downloading nsepy-0.8.tar.gz (33 kB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2022924Z [15:08:53+0000] Collecting numpy==1.19.5
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2023827Z [15:08:54+0000]   Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.9 MB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2024538Z [15:08:57+0000] Collecting pandas==1.3.1
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2025512Z [15:08:57+0000]   Downloading pandas-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.7 MB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2026293Z [15:08:59+0000] Collecting requests==2.26.0
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2027195Z [15:08:59+0000]   Downloading requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2027944Z [15:09:01+0000] Collecting scikit_learn==1.0.1
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2028928Z [15:09:01+0000]   Downloading scikit_learn-1.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (24.7 MB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2029713Z [15:09:07+0000] Collecting tensorflow==2.5.0
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2032336Z   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/dc/0e/72070fe6d5774bfc6b73e857f1747ba99b95cb808c46b709ab7c9ec757eb/tensorflow-2.5.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2034884Z [15:09:23+0000]   Downloading tensorflow-2.5.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (454.4 MB)
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2035989Z An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details.
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2040696Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2053869Z ##[error]Deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
2022-01-02T15:32:52.2056058Z App Service Application URL: http://stockprojection.azurewebsites.net```
````

Comment: I deployed my app using vscode's azure tool extension. My problem got solved.